# Python - Binascii Error while unhexlify

Tags: python, binascii

I am reading out a file, calculate the ord-number which can be used together with the ord() function.

After that I unhexlify this number to get the byte representation of this character, because I work with non-ASCII characters and write these into a file.

Everything is working fine until I'm is reading out an "CR" better known as carriage return.

My Program raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#######", line xx:
    x2 = binascii.unhexlify(format(Echr,"x"))
binascii.Error: Odd-length string
```

Do you got any idea why this error raises and how to fix this? Till now jut the CR is raising this error.

Comment: The string has an odd length. Perhaps you should show how the string is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass an odd-length string to `unhexlify`, which can only handle hex characters *in pairs*.

If you produced your hex from an integer value in the range 0-255, make sure to *pad* your hex string with a 0:

```
x2 = binascii.unhexlify(format(Echr, "02x"))
```

The `02x` formatted tells the `format()` function to fit your number in to a field of width 2, with leading zeros if the actual value is shorter:

```
>>> format(13, '02x')
'0d'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(format(10, '02x'))
'\r'
```

Using `binascii.unhexlify` together with `format()` is rather a roundabout way to create the bytes however. You can skip all that and go straight to the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr), which produces a character from an integer:

```
>>> chr(13)
'\r'
```

Comment: It is not rly an roundabout, because it is a part of my hole script. Anyway it worked. I just wonder why it does everything, except of the CR without this 02 in front of the x?

Comment: @freedome97: all your other bytes have values > 15 so produce 2 hex characters each.